# String range query in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, range

I'm trying to query data in an Elasticsearch cluster (2.3) using the following range query.  To clarify, I'm searching on a field that contains an array of values that were derived by concatenating two ids together with a count.  For example:

**Schema:**

```
{
  id1: 111,
  id2: 222,
  count: 5
}
```

The query I'm using looks like the following:

**Query:**

```
{
  "query": {
  "bool": {
    "must": {
      "range": {
        "myfield": {
          "from": "111_222_1",
          "to": "111_222_2147483647",
          "include_lower": true,
          "include_upper": true
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The `to` field uses `Integer.MAX_VALUE`

This works alright but doesn't exactly match the underlying data. Querying through other means produces more results than this method.

More strangely, trying `111_222_5` in the `from` field produces 0 results, while trying `111_222_10` *does* produce results.

How is ES (and/or Lucene) interpreting this range query and why is it producing such strange results?  My initial guess is that it's not looking at the full value of the last portion of the String and possibly only looking at the first digit.

Is there a way to specify a format for the TermRange?  I understand date ranging allows formatting.

Comment: Using `111_222_null` for the `to` value starts getting closer to accurate results, however, it still gives strange results when incrementing `from`.  Theoretically, the results should get fewer and fewer, however there is a spike when getting to 10.  This further leads me to think it is only using the first digit.  It looks like when I use `10` it starts looking for docs with count < 10, not > 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[A look here provides the answer.](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_ranges.html)

The way it's doing range is lexicographic,  5 comes before 50 comes before 6, etc.

To get around this, I reindexed using a fixed length string for the count.

```
0000000001
0000000100
0001000101
...
```

Comment: This answers the why, but the how of getting around this remains.

Do I have to reindex to use prepended 0s to do place value?

`111_222_00001`